# Variables and conditions in processing

Tags: processing

Just wondering if I want to do a loop to make every time I mousePressed to draw a circle and each time fill with 3 different colour eg yellow orange and blue and so on I use for(int countmouseClick=n; n<=3 ; n++) how should I finish the rest? Should I reset n if n=3 to n= 0?.  The circles can stay on the canvas
Not sure if it correct.

```
void mousePressed(){
   for ( int count=0; n<= 2; n++){
    fill(255,0,0);
    fill(0,255,0);
    fill(0,0,255);
    }
   circle(mouseX,mouseY,20);
```

}

//i have adopted the idea of %,  it telling me the variable n doesn't exist, why is this

```
int count;
void setup(){
  size(400,400);
  background(255);
}

void draw(){
}

void mousePressed(){
  int count=n;
  if(n>2){              //reset mouse click to 0
           n=0;
    }
  for(int n= 0;n<=2;n++){//count mouseclicked, if n<=2, n=n+1
  if(n%3=0){
    fill(255,0,0);
  }else if (n%3=1){
    fill(0,255,0);
  }
   else {
    fill(0,0,255);
}

circle(mouseX,mouseY,20);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a better way of writing the code is to  write a helper function which takes countmouseclick and return the color

you can read these articles for understanding the code below

https://processing.org/reference/modulo.html
https://processing.org/reference/switch.html

```
Color getColor(int countMouseClick){

switch(countMouseClick%3) {
  case 0:
    return COLOR.ORANGE;
  case 1:
    return COLOR.YELLOW;
    break;
  case 2:
    return COLOR.BLUE;
  default:
    return COLOR.GREEN;

}
```

Comment: Sorry haven’t gone that far. Can you explain in a more primitive code way.

Comment: it's not that hard. so basically we have something called a modulo operator. what it does is return the remainder. so basically let's say your mouseclicks are called c and currently the value if c=1 then 1%3 returns 1 and it will go ahead and execute the case of 1 and in this, it returns a yellow color. and let's say your c increased now its 2%3 return 2 and in this case blue is returned. and let's say you c =9 then 9%3 remainder is 0 so it goes and gives orange color. so based on different values it will give different colors. you can search for switch case and modulo operator for more info

Comment: so basically all we did is pass the no of mouse clicks as a value to our function which calculates some value and based on that value returns us a color. but here we are doing it will less code and not dealing with any loops and stuff. a cleaner way of writing code.

Comment: on switch case https://processing.org/reference/switch.html, on modulo operator https://processing.org/reference/modulo.html

Comment: What about only use the code within mousePressed function.  I knew I need to count the click and how do I let the program know which click to fill which colour ?

Comment: Oh I’m only at the very beginning and using processing…

Comment: can you paste the code you wrote.

Comment: Sorry I’m using mobile so may not that good. 
void mousePressed (){  for (int count=n; n<= 3; n++){ fill () circle(mouseX,mouseY, 20);}. First I don’t know how to execute fill with different colour  second I don’t know how should I reset n back to 1 or 0.

Comment: Using the provided method, and assuming that you have a variable tracking the number of mouse clicks, erase the for loop in your `mouseClicked()` method and write instead: `fill(getColor(mouseClickCount));`. This is assuming that you increase the `mouseClickCount` integer variable by 1 every time you click with the mouse (also assuming that it exists, you have to add it), so also add this line to the `mouseClicked()` method: `mouseClickCount++;`. Also, get to know the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator if you're unfamiliar with it, it's a very useful tool.